# onCreate() method being skipped

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

I am creating an app like Instagram and I am having a very hard time right now. When the users select an image they click the next button and they go to the next scene to write a caption. But what is happening is that users just upload the pictures and they don't go to the scene to add a caption. They go straight to the scene that is suppose to show AFTER they add a caption.

These are the errors that show up on my LogCat:

```
07-10 15:23:21.150 30970-31309/tabian.com.hash E/ImageLoader: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@f488c6e]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@f488c6e]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is the code I believe is failing:

GalleryFragment:

```
TextView nextScreen = view.findViewById(R.id.tvNext);
nextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Navigating to the final share screen.");

        if(isTaskRoot ()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
            GalleryFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.return_to_fragment), getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment));
            GalleryFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
            Objects.requireNonNull(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity()).finish();
        }
    }
});
```

UniversalImageLoader:

```
public static void setImage(String imgURL, ImageView image, final ProgressBar mProgressBar, String append){

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(append + imgURL, image, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            if(mProgressBar != null){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            if(mProgressBar != null){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if(mProgressBar != null){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            if(mProgressBar != null){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

***EDIT:***

```
private String mAppend = "file:/";

//use the grid adapter to adapter the images to gridview
    GridImageAdapter adapter = new 
GridImageAdapter(GalleryFragment.this.getActivity(), 
R.layout.layout_grid_imageview, mAppend, imgURLs);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (imgURLs.isEmpty()) {
        // Array list is empty, handle accordingly
    } else {
        //set the first image to be displayed when the activity fragment view is inflated
        try {
            setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);
            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "setupGridView: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: Selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));

                setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
                mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void setImage(String imgURL, ImageView image, String append){
    Log.d(TAG, "setImage: Setting image");

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.displayImage(append + imgURL, image, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

EDIT 2 !!

```
public static void setImage(String imgURL, ImageView image, final ProgressBar mProgressBar, String append){

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("Url to storage");


 storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().
addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // HERE will be your proper URI to load by Universal Image Loader
            Log.e("uri1", uri.toString());
        }
     }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

Comment: What happened with your last question?

Comment: This is wrong: GalleryFragment.this.startActivity(intent);  Replace it with getActivity().startActivity(intent); BUT I see the problem, the error isn't related with the code below. The problem is that you pass wrong url to photo in your code... Show us your code of universalimageloader when you loading image.

Comment: @DennyDog for both of them or just the one in the else statement ?

Comment: @TruongHieu I don't know

Comment: @DavidRockefeller both, but read my edited comment above again.

Comment: @DennyDog I just updated my question

Comment: And what is imgURL and what is append variabes?

Comment: When I put this in my else statement `Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity().startActivity(intent));` I get a red line under it

Comment: @DennyDog The place where my picture is stored ?

Comment: It gets stored in my firebase db . I don't have problems putting it in there

Answer (score 1):

Library universalimageloader has a problem with load image that you want to load, because you provide wrong URL to the image.

There is specified URIs in documentation that you need to use to load image. Print your `String imgUrl` before you load it and tell me what is there?

Acceptable URIs examples from [library documentation](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples)

```
"file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png" // from SD card
"file:///mnt/sdcard/video.mp4" // from SD card (video thumbnail)
"content://media/external/images/media/13" // from content provider
"content://media/external/video/media/13" // from content provider (video thumbnail)
"assets://image.png" // from assets
"drawable://" + R.drawable.img // from drawables (non-9patch images)
```

So... You want to show your photo with this url:

"file:/" + "gs://hash-a921f.appspot.com/photos/users/YqwhCwkBm8WM6Vd3PjcHHPl2suZ2/profile_photo"

This is wrong composed URI. You must to retrieve real URI for your "profile_photo" from firebase.

I think you can do it following this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

You must execute it BEFORE you execute setImage() method.

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // HERE will be your proper URI to load by Universal Image Loader
                // Now you can use setImage() method, use uri.toString() as imageUrl. Remove "append" variable in setImage() method.
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is the storage location

Comment: gs://hash-a921f.appspot.com/photos/users/YqwhCwkBm8WM6Vd3PjcHHPl2suZ2/profile_photo

Comment: This is the download URL https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hash-a921f.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fusers%2FYqwhCwkBm8WM6Vd3PjcHHPl2suZ2%2Fprofile_photo?alt=media&token=18a17ad8-c140-49c1-8a05-29d5bed9db7b

Comment: Please also discover the secret of: append + imgURL.

Comment: Man, you understand what I paste above from documentation? You have wrong URI to your image, because you compose some "append" and "imgURL" what equals wrong URL to image. Library doesn't know how to load your image. What is under "append" variable?

Comment: Did you see it ?

Comment: This ? YqwhCwkBm8WM6Vd3PjcHHPl2suZ2/

Comment: You already paste the full link to your photo. It was 

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hash-a921f.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fusers%2FYqwhCwkBm8WM6Vd3PjcHHPl2suZ2%2Fprofile_photo?alt=media&token=18a17ad8-c140-49c1-8a05-29d5bed9db7b

Comment: Yeah . When I click the `profile_photo` I gave you what they gave me

Comment: Now you must to retrieve it from firebase by method that I paste at the end of my answer and set is to universalImageLoader.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it . I tried and I got a bunch of errors . I removed some things and imported others but nothing helped me

Comment: I tried that in my Gallery Fragment and UniversalImageLoader and I just got a bunch of errors

Comment: Where should I put it ? And what file should I put it in ?

Comment: I put that code right under this line `public static void setImage(String imgURL, ImageView image, final ProgressBar mProgressBar, String append){`

Comment: I put that in In the UniversalImageLoader

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check firebase documentation to resolve firebase sdk problems.

Comment: I just added two lines of code and I am cleaning the project now and i'll show you what I get in a few

Comment: Do I need to build an apk and debug through my phone to get the URL ?

Comment: No, why this question? :D

Comment: Because I don't see the image .

Comment: I just rebuilt the project and I am looking in the LogCat, Build etc and I don't see it

Comment: Show me what you get after you downloadUri, please print uri.toString().

Comment: Where do I put that ?

Comment: Is it this ? `Log.e("uri1", uri.toString());` where do I put it ?

Comment: Print uri after you download it, in success listener: 

public void onSuccess(Uri uri) { HERE }

Comment: Still nothing prints out . Where am I suppose to be looking ?

Comment: Man, did you follow my advices? Do you have implemented getDownloadUrl() method in your code or not? Is it works? You have full documentation from Firebase how to do that.

Comment: I followed it .

Comment: I just updated my code . Look under edit 2 that's what I currently have

Comment: No, no errors . The only errors I see are the ones I posted in my question

Comment: Hello ? Are you still here ?

Comment: @DavidRockefeller I was offline. Have you worked on problem? How can I help you now?

Comment: No the same thing is still happening

Comment: I went through the code and nothing seems out of place

Comment: @DavidRockefeller Do your console print this variable?             Log.e("uri1", uri.toString());

Comment: No . The code you gave me stopped me from going on my profile page so I moved it out